# Building a web application with Factor

Tags: factor-lang, stack-based

Has anybody built a web application with [Factor](http://factorcode.org/)?  What were some of the stumbling blocks or problems that you encountered during the process?

Comment: Not even Jon Skeet can save you now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [this](http://factorlang-fornovices.blogspot.com/2007/03/creating-simple-web-application-in.html).

Comment: I was hoping for anything a bit more recent, but I guess Furnace is still the way to go.  Thanks.

Comment: Well, the latest additions to Furnace seem to have been made last December, so its not thaaaat old.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a [tutorial](http://re-factor.blogspot.com/2010/08/hello-web.html) showing some of the features of Factor's web development libraries.

There is also a [blog gitorial](https://github.com/malu/factor-blog-gitutorial) that builds a blog web application iteratively.

The Factor [source code](http://github.com/slavapestov/factor) has several working web applications under `extra/webapps`.

The concatenative.org wiki has a [page](http://concatenative.org/wiki/view/Factor/Furnace) with more information about Furnace.

Comment: Hi: Do you happen to know why the `factorcode.org` website is down?  As is planet.factor, and every other place I tried to download a Factor binary... Is this temporary or permanent?